# Difference between buffering-wrapped JdkClientHttpRequestFactory and SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory while encountering IOException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-boot-3

I have stumbled upon a weird issue I find no explanation for. It happens once the configured `RestClient` encounters any erroneous HTTP status code, for example, 401 Unauthorized.

The configuration is equal: For the sake of logging responses for development purposes, I wrap `ClientHttpRequestFactory` into `BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory`.

The only difference is what implementation I use. I switch between these two:

- `JdkClientHttpRequestFactory`
- `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`

```java
@Bean
public RestClient restClient() {
    // Switch between SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory and JdkClientHttpRequestFactory
    final var clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

    return RestClient.builder()
        .requestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory))
        .requestInterceptors(list -> list.add(new LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor()))
        .build();
}
```

Here is the logging interceptor:

```java
@Slf4j
private static class LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body, final ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // Perform the REST call.
        final var clientHttpResponse = execution.execute(request, body);
        // Copy and log the response body.
        try {
            // First InputStream read.
            log.info("#1 attempt");
            final var response = StreamUtils.copyToString(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), UTF_8);
            log.info("#1 status={}, response={}", clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().value(), response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Second InputStream read.
            log.info("#2 attempt");
            final var response = StreamUtils.copyToString(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), UTF_8);
            log.info("#2 status={}, response={}", clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().value(), response);
        }

        // Return the client response.
        return clientHttpResponse;
   }
}
```

For an unknown reason (I found nothing in the documentation), in the case of using `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` I have to somewhat call `clientHttpResponse.getBody()` twice: Once to catch the `IOException` and then to finally get the response body.

Find the log output for both cases below for better comparison on calling any endpoint returning a 4XX response:

- `JdkClientHttpRequestFactory` - expected behavior

  > ```
  > 2024-01-04T15:25:41.138+07:00  INFO 62777 --- [main] : #1 attempt
  > 2024-01-04T15:25:41.140+07:00  INFO 62777 --- [main] : #1 status=400, response={"foo": "bar"}
  > 2024-01-04T15:25:41.141+07:00  INFO 62777 --- [main] : Done
  > ```
- `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` - unexpected behavior

  > ```
  > 2024-01-04T15:26:41.518+07:00  INFO 62839 --- [main] : #1 attempt
  > 2024-01-04T15:26:41.767+07:00  INFO 62839 --- [main] : #2 attempt
  > 2024-01-04T15:26:41.769+07:00  INFO 62839 --- [main] : #2 status=400, response={"foo": "bar"}
  > 2024-01-04T15:26:41.771+07:00  INFO 62839 --- [main] : Done
  > ```

I am aware each `ClientHttpRequestFactory` has its behavior, however, I would never expect that in the case of `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` it is required to invoke `clientHttpResponse.getBody()` twice to get the actual response after catching `IOException`. While debugging, I also found out that the 2nd and subsequent calls return to the same instance.

What is the explanation that `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` behaves in that way?